# Looking for Highly stable 5v Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I want to build a custom battery pack / power supply to run a Raspberry Pi.

The board takes 5 volts and I want a 2 amp Max supply.  Does anyone know of a circuit that would help me ensure that the pi always got 5v?

I would be using 9 AA's for my battery pack. The goal would be for it to be as cheap, small, and efficient as possible.

Comment: Look for DC/DC converter with the given specs. Not on SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are battery powered, you probably want to use switching regulator for maximum battery efficiency.

The cheapest way is to buy a pre-made regulator module. '5V step down' will give you plenty of results, for example this one $1.70 with free shipping: http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/221744965891. It can take up to 24 volt input, so you can just connect your battery pack to the input.
The regulator above is using KIS-3R33S module. If you are limited in space, you can buy the module alone, and add two capacitors and two resistors.

If you want to make one yourself, I highly recommend TI 's "SIMPLE SWITCHER" series, such as LM2673. Here is an example schematics:

[image: LM2673 connection]

https://www.ti.com/product/LM2673/technicaldocuments

Note that if you going to make it on protoboard, you will want to keep the wires short and ground in one spot, as per regulator datasheet.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that, according to [this datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1575.pdf), the LM2575 can only source 1A and the OP needs 2A.

Comment: Thanks, changed to LM2673 which is 3A (and two extra capacitors)

Comment: Your upvote is well deserved +1

Comment: I was going to suggest a buck-boost topology to make full use of those 9 AA batteries, but the depleted voltage for an alkaline cell is 0.8-1V, coming in right at the 8V input minimum. Your choice of regulator is very well chosen!

Comment: If you do make your own board, follow the layout in (Evaluation Board figure 2)[http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snva013d/snva013d.pdf] as closely as you can. The component selection, component placement, and all of the wide copper traces on the top foil layer are *very important*. My colleagues at National Semiconductor put a lot of effort into this example layout to help you succeed. Switchers don't like long slim wires, or extra through-hole vias, or solderless breadboards.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to design a buck converter.

1) It might not be the cheapest

2) It can be small (depending on the inductor size)

3) Most certainly is efficient

The buck converter is also the best option to be used with batteries as AA batteries are not constant discharge. Hence the buck converter actively adjusts itself to provide a constant output.

The only downside is that designing a buck converter isnt easy, however these days you can order this stuff online. Look up DC-DC Buck converters are choose an appropriate module.

Answer (score -4):

use 7805 voltage regulator it will give you 5v constant and around 1.5 amps of current check the data sheet for current rating there are more regulators are  available for higher current rating.

Comment: That would be probably the least efficient way of doing it - the only way to arrange the batteries to have enough forward voltage for a 7805 would be 9 in series, so you would be supplying 13.5V to the regulator and dropping 8.5V across it. At 1.5A, that would be a power dissipation of almost *13W*. The size of the required heatsink would probably also make it the largest possible solution.

Comment: well some one also suggested a regulator

Comment: @user72662, they suggested a *switching* regulator, which is way more efficient than the linear regulator you suggested. That's Tom's point.